# Fragment order after onSavedInstanceState

Tags: android, fragment

The order of Fragments are not the same after the Activity was onSavedInstanceState like there where added, if a remove was performed.

Example:

```
add RedFragment
add GreenFragmen
add BlueFragment
```

now getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments gives:

```
list[0]-> RedFragment
list[1]-> GreenFragmen
list[2]-> BlueFragment
```

good so far...

next:

```
remove RedFragment
```

now getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments gives:

```
list[1]-> GreenFragmen
list[2]-> BlueFragment
```

the indexes of the array seems broken.

next:

```
add YellowFragment
```

now getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments gives:

```
list[0]-> YellowFragment
list[1]-> GreenFragmen
list[2]-> BlueFragment
```

the the new fragment take place at the removed index.(bug?)

in UI everything is in the order like it was added:

```
1-> GreenFragmen
2-> BlueFragment
3-> YellowFragment
```

but if my activity going killed and onSaveInstanceState() is called, after resuming the activity the order of my fragments are not like before:

```
1-> YellowFragment
2-> GreenFragmen
3-> BlueFragment
```

all FragmentTransaction are done with getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()

Comment: if you call addToBackStack(String name) then order will remain same.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)

Comment: This is true. But in my case a backstack is not what i want. I want to be able to remove any Fragment at any time. So a Stack will cut my flexibility.